# Special conformal killing fields - solving for integral curves.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

For each $b\in\mathbb R^d$, let a vector field $X_b:\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb R^d$ be defined as follows:
\begin{align}
  X_b(x) = 2(b\cdot x)x - x^2 b,
\end{align}
where $x^2 = x\cdot x$.  This is the conformal killing field that generates special conformal transformations.

> How does one solve for the integral curves of this monster?

Apparently, the (local) answer (which I've only ever seen magically pulled out of a hat) is as follows:
\begin{align}
  x(t) = \frac{x_0 - x_0^2(tb)}{1-2x_0\cdot(tb) + x_0^2(tb)^2} \tag{$\star$}
\end{align}
How can one at least somewhat systematically arrive at this?  The system of ODEs one needs to solve is non-linear and coupled; I'm rather at a loss as to how to even begin attacking it.

Note: eq. $(\star)$ written down and discussed briefly in

*A Mathematical Introduction to Conformal Field theory* by Schottenloher, 2nd ed., p. 17.

It is also all over the place in the theoretical physics literature where one sees statements to the effect of "integrating the infinitesimal version of the special conformal transformation gives..." and then $(\star)$ is written down.

**Progress!** I think I've almost figured it out using a tricky change of variables.  We want to solve
\begin{align}
  \dot x = 2(b\cdot x)x - x^2 b.
\end{align}
Make a change of variables
\begin{align}
  y = \frac{x}{x^2}
\end{align}
and after some algebra, one shows that $y$ satisfies
\begin{align}
  \dot y = -b
\end{align}
which has as a solution
\begin{align}
  y = y_0 - tb,
\end{align}
so now we simply need to solve the algebraic equation
\begin{align}
  \frac{x}{x^2} = \frac{x_0}{x_0^2} - tb.
\end{align}
The solution quoted above certainly solves this, but how does one solve this equation "from scratch?"

**Solution** As pointed out by, @[HunsLundmark](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1242/hans-lundmark), the algebraic equation
\begin{align}
  \frac{x}{x^2} = A
\end{align}
can be readily solved to give $x = A/A^2$, so setting $A = x_0/x_0^2-tb$ gives the desired result.

Comment: Your substitution $y=x/x^2$ is simpler that mine.

Comment: @Kirill Agreed, but how does one solve the equation at the end for $x$?

Comment: How did you get $y\cdot(\dot y+b)=0$? That doesn't imply $\dot y=-b$. All I get is $\frac{dy}{dt}=-b$.

Comment: @Kirill I probably made an error, let me check my algebra.

Comment: You can solve the algebraic equation you got with by computing $(x^2)' = 2x^4\times\mathrm{const}$, so $x^2$ also has a nice closed-form solution.

Comment: @Kirill I found where I went wrong; I hadn't originally simply directly computed $\dot y$, so I had obtained the identity $y\cdot(\dot y + b)$ which is of course still true but not what we want.    I hope you don't mind if I post my own answer as well and perhaps accept it since it's a bit simpler?  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: To solve the algebraic equation $x/x^2=A$, note that it implies that $x=\lambda A$ for some scalar $\lambda$; thus $\lambda A/(\lambda^2 A^2)=A$, so $\lambda = 1/A^2$. Hence $x=A/A^2$.

Comment: @HansLundmark Very slick; thanks.

Answer (score 5):

**1.** Introduce a new independent variable $s=bt$ to get rid of $b$, and
w.l.o.g., assume that the vector $b$ points along $e_1$, $b=be_1$:
$$ \frac{dx}{ds} = 2x_1x-x^2e_1, $$
$$ \dot x_1 = x_1^2-x_2^2-\cdots-x_n^2, \qquad \dot x_i = 2x_1x_i, $$
where, since $x_1$ is special, the index $i$ ranges over $2,\ldots,n$.

**2.** Introduce the change of variables $(z, w) = \left(x_1, (\sum_i
  x_i^2)^{1/2}\right)$, so that we need to solve
$$ \dot z = z^2-w, \qquad \dot w = 4zw. $$
Differentiate $\dot z$ to get
$$ \ddot z = 6z\dot z-4z^3. $$

**3.** Now here I cheated and used Mathematica: it gives the general solution as
$$ z(s) = -\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{s+\gamma} +
  \frac{1}{s+\bar\gamma}\right), $$
where $\gamma = \alpha + i\beta$ is a complex constant.

**3a.** Another way is
to look for poles of $z$ by substituting $z(s)=a(s+\gamma)^b$,
expanding in Laurent series at $s=-\gamma$ and observing that the
resulting leading order equation
$$ a b(b-1)(s+\gamma)^{b-2} =
6a^2b(s+\gamma)^{2b-1}-4a^3(s+\gamma)^{3b} $$
has solutions $b=-1$ and $a=0, -\frac12, -1$. Also note that the
Laurent series at $s=\infty$ also gives $z\sim -(\text{$1$ or $\frac12$})s^{-1}$. A complex-differentiable function with only regular singularities on $\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$ must be rational, so only $a=-1$ with one pole and $a=-\frac12$ with two poles make sense. A rational function with two order-1 poles and finite at $\infty$ must be the sum of only the two pole terms, as above. Since $z$ should be real, the second pole is $\bar\gamma$. Not completely rigourous, but good enough.

**4.** Integrating $w$ is easy:
$$ (\log w)' = 4z, \qquad w(s) = w(0)\left(
\frac{\alpha^2+\beta^2}{(s+\alpha)^2+\beta^2} \right)^2. $$

Substituting $z, w$ into $\dot z$ gives the relationship between
$\alpha$ and $\beta$:
$$ \frac{\alpha^2-\beta^2}{(\alpha^2+\beta^2)^2} = z_0^2-w_0, $$
so therefore
$$ \gamma = \frac{-1}{z_0+i w_0}, \qquad \Re\gamma =
\frac{-z_0}{z_0^2+w_0^2}. $$

Integrating $x_i$ is as easy as $w$:
$$ x_i(s) = x_i(0)
\frac{\gamma\bar\gamma}{(s+\gamma)(s+\bar\gamma)}. $$

**5.** Finally, writing it out in full, letting $\rho_0^2 =
x_1(0)^2+\cdots+x_n(0)^2$:
$$\begin{aligned}
 \vec x &= \frac{1}{(s+\gamma)(s+\bar\gamma)}
\left(-(s+\Re\gamma)e_1+x_i(0)\gamma\bar\gamma \right)
\\&= \frac{-(s\rho_0^2-z_0)e_1 +
  x_i(0)}{\rho_0^2(s+\gamma)(s+\bar\gamma)}
\\&= \frac{\vec x(0) - s\rho_0^2e_1}{1-2z_0s+\rho_0^2s^2}.
\end{aligned}$$

This is clearly identical to your formula, once $t=s/b$ and $b=be_1$
are substituted back in.

Comment: Wow, bravo for all this effort.  The crazy thing is that I saw this exactly at the same time that I think I've almost figured out a really tricky way to do this.  See my edit to the question (the Progress! section)  I'll read through this as well.  Thanks again.